# How to make appear a div when a img is being hovered

Tags: html, css, image, hover

When I hover the over an image `img1`, I want the corresponding text `text1` to appear. The same goes for img2 and text2, and so on.

Here is the code of what I tried, but the text doesn't appear when I hover on the images. What am I doing wrong?

here is my html

```
<section>
    <div class="planche">
        <img class="img1" src="./images/1.jpg">
        <img class="img2" src="./images/2.jpg">
        <img class="img3" src="./images/3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="text1">
        <p>
            TEXTE 1
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="text2">
        <p>
            TEXTE 2
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="text3">
        <p>
            TEXTE 3
        </p>
    </div>      
</section>
```

and here is my css:

```
.img1:hover .text1 {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to use JavaScript / jQuery for this? I don't believe it is possible in plain CSS with the current structure - Alternative, could the text divs be moved into the planche div

Comment: This is because of how css works. Your notation means: “ if `.img1` is being hovered, apply rules to `.text1` that is within the `.img1`. This cannot work. The best you can do with css use siblings selector but it would require changes to html too.

Comment: While jQuery is not required, JavaScript is as there is no parent selector in CSS, so there’s no way to select the relevant `<div>` based on the hovered image.

Comment: jQuery is NOT needed for this

Comment: Yes, I've already edited my comment to show this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One pure CSS approach is to surround each image in a semantically friendly `figure` and use the general sibling combinator (`~`) to target each associated text `div`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator):

> The general sibling combinator (~) separates two selectors and matches
>   the second element only if it follows the first element (though not
>   necessarily

immediately), and both are children of the same parent element.

```css
.planche1:hover ~ .text1,
.planche2:hover ~ .text2,
.planche3:hover ~ .text3 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <figure class="planche planche1">
    <img class="img1" src="http://placekitten.com/100/50?image=1" alt="description goes here">
  </figure>
  <figure class="planche planche2">
    <img class="img2" src="http://placekitten.com/100/50?image=2" alt="description goes here">
  </figure>
  <figure class="planch planche3">
    <img class="img3" src="http://placekitten.com/100/50?image=3" alt="description goes here">
  </figure>
  <div class="text1">
    <p>
      TEXTE 1
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="text2">
    <p>
      TEXTE 2
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="text3">
    <p>
      TEXTE 3
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sgb3eoak/6/)

Comment: Use [placekitten](https://placekitten.com), you know you want to